# Contribution to Change in Year of Year Growth of a Ratio

Tags: percentages

I am trying to calculate Contribution to Change per Category for this problem:

I have different categories in my online shop: 
[TABLE WITH NUMBERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KnD0.png)

A) Electronics
B) Cosmetics
C) Clothes

I am interested in each categories' contribution to growth for the conversion rate. The Conversion Rate is Sales/Clicks.

In the example you can see that the Conversion Rate grew by 37%. How much did each category contribute to this growth?

Here are the example numbers:

```
CATEGORY     SALES 2019  SALES 2020
Electronics  20          50
Cosmetics    10          7
Clothes      15          17
Total        45          74

CAT          Clicks 2019 Clicks 2020
Electronics  320          550
Cosmetics    500          270
Clothes      470          730
Total        1290         1550

Sales/Clicks 2019         2020
Electronics  6%          9%
Cosmetics    2%          3%
Clothes      3%          2%
Total        3%          5%
```

-> in total conversion rate grew by 37% ( if you take the exact numbers)

**How much did each category contribute to this change?**